# Selecting NULL and NOT NULL values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, null

SQL beginner here, trying to figure out how I can grab both `NULL` and `NOT NULL` values from a table in MySQL. I've tried omitting specifying null and not null to see if that would grab both types, but no luck.

```
SELECT
  COUNT('') as cnt
  FROM returned_items ri
  LEFT JOIN returns r ON ri.return_id = r.return_id
  WHERE r.storenum IN (11)
```

With `NULL` and `NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT
  COUNT('') as cnt
  FROM returned_items ri
  LEFT JOIN returns r ON ri.return_id = r.return_id
  WHERE r.storenum IN (11)
  AND ri.disposition is NULL AND NOT NULL
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any other possible values other then null and not null? I think you just need to remove check for disposition

Comment: Also "AND ri.disposition is NULL AND NOT NULL" is saying it must equal both NULL and NOT NULL which is not possible.

Comment: Regardless of the contradiction the syntax should be AND ri.disposition is NULL AND ri.dispositionNOT NULL
in this case the column has to be repeated in every condition

Comment: When you do a `LEFT JOIN`, conditions on the second table should normally be in the `ON` clause, not `WHERE`. Otherwise, it will filter out any rows in the first table that have no match, because `r.storenum` will be `NULL` in those rows. So it becomes effectively the same as `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. There nothing in the first query that checks `ri.disposition`, so it should return both null and non-null values.

Comment: Can you show some sample input and the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you really need that condition since you are trying to get both having `NULL` and `NOT NULL` ... means you are trying to get all the records and thus the condition makes no sense but you can have two different queries and perform a `UNION ALL` like (though not sure why you would do that)

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) as cnt
  FROM returned_items ri
  LEFT JOIN returns r ON ri.return_id = r.return_id
  WHERE r.storenum = 11
  AND ri.disposition is NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  COUNT(*) as cnt
  FROM returned_items ri
  LEFT JOIN returns r ON ri.return_id = r.return_id
  WHERE r.storenum = 11
  AND ri.disposition is NOT NULL
```